# How can I enable a button to launch the next activity after taking a photo?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-activity, camera

I want to activate the button after the user fills the editText and takes the photo, to launch the next activity. I already granted access to the Manifest. XML, and added some code to the activity. The camera opens fine but can't store the picture nor launch the next activity. Please, let me know how I can do this.

Here's my activity:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_idcheck.*

class idcheck1 : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {

        private const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 1
        private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_idcheck)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.x)
        x.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Getstarted::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.verificame)
        verificame.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, TYCacreedores::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        upload.setOnClickListener {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                    CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE
                )


            }


        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray

    ) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] === PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Bueeno, negaste el permiso para acceder a tu cámara. " +
                            " No te apures, permitelo en configuraciones en tu teléfono.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()

            }

        }

    }
}
```

and here's my layout

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/Darkest"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".idcheck1">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="563dp"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded1"
            android:columnCount="1"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/x"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="320dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/close_circle" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Tú identidad."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                    android:text="¿Cúal es tu cédula?"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/correo"
                    android:layout_width="281dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded3"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                    android:hint="03700000001"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="11"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorDark"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                    android:text="Sube pruebas."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                    android:text="*Cédula de ambos lados."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsregular"
                    android:text="*Foto sosteniendo tú cédula."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/upload"
                    android:layout_width="174dp"
                    android:layout_height="83dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/upload" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/verificame"
                    android:layout_width="247dp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton3"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:text="Verificame!"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorDark"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You are using startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) to get camera photo. But you are not listening for results.

startActivityForResult opens new activity in this case it is system activity for making photos. After taking photo this activity is closing and result are returning to calling activity (idcheck1).

To read those results your activity must override function onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) where you can decide what to do with acquired data.

requestCode parameter identifies from which activity comes data. So if you startedActivityForResult with CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE you need to listen for the same request code on result.
resultCode is status how activity ended like Activity.RESULT_OK, Activity.RESULT_CANCELED or other
data is intent data acquired from activity

Example code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

     if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val imageBitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap //get Photo Image
            
            //here you can add aditional logic after making photo. Start another activity/enable button/save image/check EditText etc.
    }
}
```

or with newer api

```
resultLauncher.launch(intent); // replace  startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val intent = result.data
        val imageBitmap = intent?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        //here you can add aditional logic after making photo. Start another activity/enable button/save image etc.
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: I tried this suggestion before but found out that onActivityResult is deprecated. Therefore, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: If deprecated is a problem for you I edited my answer showing how to use newer version of this code.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking the time, to answer the original question, yet nobody is asking whose problem it is now.